# How to delete whatsapp without a SD card or a SIM card installed?

Tags: applications, htc-desire, whatsapp-messenger

I have taken out my SIM card and SD card as I have a new phone, how do I delete whatsapp, as messages are still being received to my old phone?

Comment: In addition to the [gettchang's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/50769/23379) below, you will *not* be receiving any messages to the old phone. You will receive new messages to the new device which has your SIM card. So no more ***..messages are still being received to my old phone...*** :)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Whatsapp from Google Play or from the phone's Application Manager (In the Samsung Galaxy S4, `Settings > More > Application Manager`).

If it's a pre-installed app and cannot be uninstalled by regular means, clear its data via Application Manager. In the Application Manager, click Whatsapp and you might see buttons like `Clear data` and `Clear cache`.

Comment: You might factory reset the old phone as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the WhatsApp on your new phone, and sign-in with the same number. WhatsApp will automatically stop forwarding the message to your old phone, and you'll start receiving the messages on your new phone.

To uninstall WhatsApp from your phone, you can go to `Settings > Application Manager > Scroll down to WhatsApp > Click on it > Click on uninstall` and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install WhatsApp on your new phone and sign-in with the new phone. After you have signed in and verfied the account, WhatsApp automatically changes the password. The old phone which uses the old password won't be allowed to connect to the WhatsApp webservice anymore.